# Is $S^1 \to [-1,1]$ a covering?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p \colon S^1 \to [-1,1]$, $(x,y) \mapsto x$ be the vertical projection. Is this a cover? It seems to be one.

**Edit**: Why it seems to be one: For every $x \in (-1,1)$, we find some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $U := B_\varepsilon(x) \subseteq (-1,1)$. Then $p^{-1}(U) \cong U \times S^0$ since the preimage of~$U$ is a disjoint union of two open subsets of $S^1$. For $x \in \{-1,1\}$, we could choose $U := B_1(x) \cap [-1,1]$. Then $p^{-1}(U) \cong U \times \{*\}$ since the preimage of $U$ is one open subset of $S^1$.

Comment: Why does it seem like a cover? Because it's continuous and surjective?

Comment: Note that for $x\in (-1,1),\ p^{-1}(U)$ has two connected components homeomorphic to $U$, while for $x\in \{-1,1\},\ p^{-1}(U)$ has single connected component homeomorphic to $U$. In the definition of covering, you need a single discrete space $D$ indexing the sheets, but here you have two different spaces, singleton and two point set, which can't be homeomorphic since they are of different cardinalities.

Comment: Then my professor had a wierd definition, making $D$ depended on $x$.

Comment: You should check with your teacher is that what they really meant. I'm using definition from Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space.

Comment: Actually, let me correct myself, if you look at $p^{-1}(U)$ for $x \in\{-1,1\}$, it's connected open set, but restriction of $p$ on it is not even injective. I think this is analogous to gimbal lock (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Applications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\{-1,1\}$ and $U$ (small enough) open neighbourhood of $x$. $p^{-1}(U)$ is an open arc of $S^1$ and in particular, it is connected. If we restrict $p$ to $p^{-1}(U)$, it is not injective because $(x_0,\pm y_0)$ are both mapped to $x_0$, but connectedness of $p^{-1}(U)$ prevents us from forming disjoint union $V_1\cup V_2 = p^{-1}(U)$ such that $p|_{V_i}$ is homeomorphism.

Note that we know that $p^{-1}(U)$ should be split into the union of two connected open sets due to the fact that this happens for any $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: I forgot that a certain diagram has to commute: If $h\colon p^{-1}(U)\to U\times D$ is the homeomorphism and $\mathrm{pr}_U\colon U\times D\to U$ is the canonical projection, then $p|_{p^{-1}(U)}=\mathrm{pr}_U\circ h$.

Answer (score 2):

No. The preimage of either $\pm 1$ under $p$ is a singleton, while all the other points have fibres of cardinality $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers correctly address your specific function, but let me give you a bit more general results:

No continuous map $S^1\to [-1,1]$ is a covering map. In fact, no map $X\to Y$ is a covering map, given both $X$, $Y$ are path connected, $\pi_1(X)\neq 0$ and $\pi_1(Y)=0$. That's because a covering map $p:X\to Y$ induces an injective group homomorphism $\pi_1(p):\pi_1(X)\to\pi_1(Y)$, which is the important result in covering maps theory.

Another reason that no map $S^1\to [-1,1]$ is a covering map, is because covering maps are local homeomorphisms. But these spaces are not locally homeomorphic. In fact no open neighbourhood of $-1$ in $[-1,1]$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $S^1$. Because it has an "end", which formally can be seen as non cut-point (i.e. a point such that its removal doesn't disconnect the space). This of course gives us another, different generalization: no map $X\to Y$ between non-locally homeomorphic spaces is a covering map.